# Modify the framebuffer in Windows

Tags: windows, gpu, framebuffer

Is there a way to modify the framebuffer before it is drawn ?
Let say I want to set red values to zero in the entire screen in any desktop application.

1) Catch drawing event and get framebuffer

2) Get each pixel and set R=0 to RGB value (with a GPU langage to avoid GPU->CPU memory tranfer)

3) Draw modified framebuffer

Comment: I guess use opengl to modify your framebuffer isn't the answer your looking for, do you? I just know ways of modifying the frames of special render widgets, but that would then be so far the CPU GPU communication whcih you want to avoid, am I right?

Comment: @Zaibis, I just want to modify the entire screen of the desktop (independent of what applications are running) just before it is drawn - ie 60 times each second if screen is set at 60Hz.

Answer (score 2):

Ha I found it what you probably are looking for:

Direct Kernel Object Manipulation

It's a Windows API that can write such filter drivers, you are looking for.
They could grant you full access to the Kernel memory and let you modify it.
As far you can hook filesystems and locations, as the Kernel memory itself and lower level network management with it, even can crash the OS itself, I would bet you could hook GPU informations before they get comitted to the gpu!

Here is a short description of it:

http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/win-usa-04/bh-win-04-butler.pdf

An API under windows which is able to do these hooks is for example:

MS Detours

I'm not willed to work me in that API but from the description it should be able to do that.

Comment: I've already tried a similar method. I've injected a DLL in programs and hook some GDI API (BitBlt, StretchBlt...). That works on some programs, but not all of them. Some applications use Direct2D... And modify each pixel in a loop is an heavy computation on CPU.

Comment: Hm but at least its a possible way. The gdi API i was lookign for too, but that one is same as openglt and directx just application related. I'm almost sure, there won't be an easy way to do this. And specially on Windows I guess it wont be cheap in recources to do so. but such kernel hook API is at least an way.

Comment: @Michael Have you tried already different API's? maybe mine, or another one is able to handle it better as the one you tried it with does?

Comment: Yes that works but there is still an issue... Get the pixels buffer from the GPU (GetDIBits), modify them on CPU and send them back to GPU (SetDIBits) is way too costly. That's why I need to modify the pixels on the GPU directly.

Comment: It should be possible using Direct2D I guess.

Comment: @Michael That's what I was suggesting, too. But didn't you say these API's can just access the applications framebuffer?!

Comment: Not exactly... In fact, I intercept paint messages sent by class controls, let the control process the messages, copy the part of screen concerned in a memory device context (BitBlt), modify the pixels (GetDIBits, modification, SetDIBits) and copy the memory buffer to the screen. I don't modify the framebuffer directly.

Comment: @MarekCzaplicki no. Sadly, I gave up.